# calling ant task in my plugin and redirect the output to the console

Tags: ant, eclipse-plugin, osgi

In my eclipse plugin, I am trying to execute an Ant task and to redirect the output to the eclipse console
Here is my code:

```
    AntRunner runner = new AntRunner();
    runner.addBuildLogger("myplugin.AntLogger");        

    String projectPath = getProject().getLocation().toString();
    String buildFileLocation = projectPath + File.separator + "build.xml";
    runner.setBuildFileLocation(buildFileLocation);
    runner.setExecutionTargets(new String[] { "build-for-device" });
```

The AntLogger code is:

```
public class AntLogger extends org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger {

private IOConsole console = new IOConsole("Ant", null);
private IOConsoleOutputStream outputStream = console.newOutputStream();

public AntLogger() {
    ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager()
            .addConsoles(new IConsole[] { console });
}

@Override
protected void printMessage(String message, PrintStream stream, int priority) {
    super.printMessage(message, stream, priority);
    try {
        outputStream.write(message + "\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

and I added the ant.jar to the plugin.xml

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ant.core.extraClasspathEntries">
  <extraClasspathEntry
        library="ant.jar">
  </extraClasspathEntry>
</extension>
```

No matter what I do I keep getting class not found exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/DefaultLogger
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntCorePreferences$WrappedClassLoader.findClass(AntCorePreferences.java:116)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.AntClassLoader.loadClassPlugins(AntClassLoader.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:47)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.createLogger(InternalAntRunner.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.addBuildListeners(InternalAntRunner.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.ant.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.ant.core.AntRunner.run(AntRunner.java:475)
```

Comment: do you have ant.jar in your classpath?

Comment: yes, It's added in the extension point and I have double checked this over and over.

Comment: maybe it can't be found at runtime? Or ant.jar does not contain that class?

Comment: thanks, but ant.jar contains the class and I am running this im my  plugin AntCorePreferences corePreferences = AntCorePlugin.getPlugin().getPreferences();
URL[] urls = corePreferences.getURLs();  and I can see the path to the ant.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After banging my head over this I finally found the solution:

The AntLogger class cannot be part of the plugin project.
I moved the AntLogger to a different java project named it EclipseAntLogger, then I added the project jar to the plugin extension point like this:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ant.core.extraClasspathEntries">
  <extraClasspathEntry
        library="lib/EclipseAntLogger.jar">
  </extraClasspathEntry>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to add `ant.jar` and other necessary jars to the `AntRunner` instance?

```
public void setCustomClasspath(URL[] customClasspath)
```

#wildstabinthedark